# How to get the output of especially no-layer in keras?

Tags: python, api, keras, backend

This is a pretty trivial question that I haven't been able to find the answer to.

I am trying to show the output of kears backend shape.

Because i don't understand the API. So, i made a small architecture using keras code.

Here is the test code.

```
xx = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,2,3),name='inputs')
x1=tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='flat')(xx)
x2=tf.keras.backend.shape(xx)[1:4]
Outputs=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='tanh',name='output')(x1)
model=tf.keras.models.Model(xx,Outputs)

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mse,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))

model.fit(tran, y, epochs=3, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I want to know the x2=tf.keras.backend.shape(xx)[1:4]; however, It doesn't exist in model.layer.

[image]

[image]

The reason I think is that x2 and output layer are not connected, but i can't connect the x2.

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: x2 is a variable that contains the shape of a previous layer. it's not a layer and for this reason, it doesn't appear in the model summary. u can use it like every other python variable. if you do print(x2) you can see its value

Comment: And you don't even need to do any of that, the shape you want is already available in model.summary(), its the shape of the first layer (inputs).

Comment: Thank you!!! I could get the value using the K.function. I'm so appreciate to your comments. Enjoy your day!